# Expresssing the number of objects

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> G is generated by 2k+t number of 7-cycles.

Edit:
I found the following expressions

> then the product set A X B has the arithmetic n X m number of elements.

in https://books.google.com/books?isbn=0793185149, and

> If A[21] is the array to be checked and the maximum value that it stores is M, then take another array B[M] with M number of elements.

in https://books.google.com/books?isbn=9380599021

which convinced me that my sentence is correct.

Thank you, for your attentions.

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'numbers'?

Comment: I do not know!!

Comment: Without context, neither do we.

Answer (score 1):

To a mathematician, these look horrible. Much better is simply

> G is generated by 2k+t 7-cycles.

and

> then the product set A x B has n x m elements.

I understand that the first writer (was it you?) was reluctant to leave t and 7 so close together, but my version is clear enough. As for your second example, it looks more like a train crash than a sentence -- perhaps it was a cut-and-paste error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to put a determiner before 2k+t number.

Comment: like this: G is generated by some 2k+t number of 7-cycles?

Comment: I think 2k+t number is a formula here. Maybe the sentence should be something like this: "G is generated by a 2k+t number of 7-cycles."

Comment: If you have any other clarifications regarding this, kindly don't hesitate to ask. If you think I was able to answer your question, please don't forget to accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: I'd prefer a verb. G is generated by running 2k+t number of 7-cycles?

Comment: Well, there are lots of ways to construct proper sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Your example uses the form *G is generated by X number of Ys*, with complicated forms of X and Y.

Let's look at another (equivalent) example first for simplicity: *juice is generated by five number of machines*. Although there are instances where this form is used, e.g. ["My land runs 5,000 head of cattle."](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle) (- Wikipedia), the form is more often written simply as *juice is generated by five machines*, dropping the phrase "number of".

Returning to your example, you would simply have *G is generated by X Ys*, or with your original terms, *G is generated by (2k+t) 7-cycles*. I have inserted brackets to reduce ambiguity, but the presence of two mathematical expressions so close to each other is non-ideal.

*Number* is awkward in this context since it doesn't identify any part of the unit (7-cycle). If these 7-cycles are periodic, try **G is generated by 2k+t periods of 7-cycles.** Otherwise, choose some identifying aspect of the 7-cycles to use instead of *periods*.

Finally, a note about plurality. "*head* of cattle" (with the singular form *head*) is a specialist term in this context. In the form *X 'count(s)' of Ys*, the word used in place of *count(s)* should normally be singular if X=1 and plural otherwise. The word used in place of *Ys* should normally be plural. If we used the simpler form *X Ys*, then we would use a singular form for *Ys* if X=1, and a plural form otherwise.

Returning to the juice example, the following are all grammatically correct:

- Juice is generated by one machine.
- Juice is generated by five machines.
- Juice is generated by one group of machines.
- Juice is generated by five groups of machines.

In your case, if you retain the algebraic expression *2k+t*, then *periods* should be always be plural.

Comment: @PhilSweet Thanks for taking the time to point out the issue about grammatical number. I now see what you were getting at and have addressed it in my edited answer. Let me know if I've read your point correctly.

Comment: @ lawrence I've cleaned out the old comments.

Comment: Consider "juice is now being produced by half the number of machines" vs "juice is now being produced by half the machines". "Number" here is a placeholder for a longer phrase such as "number that we used to use". And I suspect "number" in the OP's example replaces "number of cycles". When I mentally unpack the OP's sentence, I end up with "G is generated by 2k+t number of cycles of 7-cycles (or number of periods of 7-cycles). Which is a long way of getting around to saying I think the singular number is correct here. I would write it as "G is generated by running 2k+t interations of 7-cycles.

Comment: On *half*: the shorter *X Ys* pattern holds for your first 2 examples: X="half the number of" Ys="machines"; and X="half" Ys="the machines". On *number of*: the phrasing still sounds awkward when there is an actual number before the phrase (5 number of cycles/periods); the plural *5 numbers of periods* sounds marginally better but still awkward. The number *2k+t* already names *how many*, so *2k+t number of periods of* sounds like the doubled phrase *number number of periods of*. On *iterations* replacing *periods* - yes, that can work.